# How to check if a string exists in a List

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, contacts

Here is my code:

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
     return contactList;
}
```

What I want is to compare all my contacts to one string and if they don't match, then to add that contact  to my DB. The issue here is if I add the below code part, is that it checks if a single string matches and if it doesn't it gets add. I can tell that the code is wrong but I can't fix it.

```
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       
for (Contact cn : contacts) {
    if (!(cn.getName().contains(substring))) {
        // Inserting Contacts
        db.addContact(new Contact(record.get("9"), getDateTime()));
    }
}
```

Comment: edited: `List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts(); ` outside the for loop.

Comment: sorry my mistake when posting the code, it is like that in my code though :p

Comment: and what's the problem? `cn.getName().contains(substring)` not works as expected?

Comment: The problem is that I want if not even a single contact matches to the List, to add it to the DB but right now even if just one contact mismatches the List it gets add

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
boolean shouldAddToDB = true;    
for (Contact cn : contacts) {
    if ((cn.getName().contains(substring))) {
        shouldAddToDB = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (shouldAddToDB) {
    // Inserting Contacts
    db.addContact(new Contact(record.get("9"), getDateTime()));
}
```